# Matrix Representation of Four Dimensional Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory

According to Peskin and Schroeder page no.39,

> Just to see that we have this right, let us look at one particular representation (which we will simply pull out of a hat). Consider 4 x 4 matrices
> $$ ({\cal J}^{\mu\nu})_{\alpha\beta} = i(\delta^{\mu}_{\alpha}\delta^{\nu}_{\beta} - \delta^{\mu}_{\beta}\delta^{\nu}_{\alpha}). \tag{3.18}$$

How did the book arrive at this matrix representation from the following realization?

> $$ J^{\mu\nu} = i(x^\mu\partial^\nu-x^\nu\partial^\mu). \tag{3.16}$$

Comment: (3.16) is the generalization to four dimensions of (3.15), as the book says. It is a representation of the $J^{\mu \nu}$ operator acting on fields, whereas (3.18) acts on four-vectors.

Comment: They are different representations of the same algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does the realization (3.16) act on a 4-dimensional vector?
$$ J^{\mu\nu} x_\alpha= i(x^\mu\delta^\nu_\alpha-x^\nu\delta^\mu_\alpha)  \\
=i(\delta^\nu_\alpha \delta^\mu_\beta -  \delta^\nu_\beta  \delta^\mu_\alpha)x^\beta =-({\cal J}^{\mu\nu})_{\alpha\beta} x^\beta ~~. $$

If the sign grated on you, you could raise indices of the 4-representation matrix $\cal J$ to be  transforming a covariant vector instead, $ ({\cal J}^{\mu\nu})_\beta ^{~~~\alpha} x_\alpha $, if so inclined.